# python - inspect doesn't work well with FunctionType generated functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-generation, inspect

Here is my code, what I want is being able to dynamically generate some function and print it into a file.

```
import types
import inspect

def create_function(name, args):

    def y(a,b,c): 
        print "working!"

    new_varnames = ("d","e","f")

    y_code = types.CodeType(args, \
    y.func_code.co_nlocals, \
    y.func_code.co_stacksize, \
    y.func_code.co_flags, \
    y.func_code.co_code, \
    y.func_code.co_consts, \
    y.func_code.co_names, \
    new_varnames, \
    y.func_code.co_filename, \
    name, \
    y.func_code.co_firstlineno, \
    y.func_code.co_lnotab)


    return types.FunctionType(y_code, y.func_globals, name)
```

Here is the output

```
>>> myfunc = create_function('myfunc', 3)
>>> myfunc(d=1,e=2,f=3)
working!
>>> print inspect.getsource(myfunc)
    def y(a,b,c): 
        print "working!"
```

I'm a bit desapointed, I would have like to have instead:

```
def myfunc(d,e,f):
    print "working!"
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python function objects do not contain their source code. They contain *byte code only*, plus a filename and the starting line number, if they were loaded from a file.

You copied that metadata over when you created your `CodeType()` object:

```
y.func_code.co_filename,
# ...
y.func_code.co_firstlineno,
```

Python then uses that information to load source from the original file; for tracebacks and for `inspect.getsource()`. Since you copied the original `y` function metadata, `inspect.getsource()` found the original source file and gave you back the source definition for `y`.

You'd have to produce a *new* file, write that to disk, and adjust the `co_filename` and `co_firstlineno` attributes of the code object if you wanted to produce different output. In practice, noone bothers with that.